# jQuery autocomplete: if user writes down a match, callback function wont get called

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have an autocomplete jQuery feature for my text field, suggesting programming languages:

```
Java
C++
PHP
```

Once the user clicks a suggestion, a callback function is called which sets the hidden ID of the language, gotten by the ajax request.

The problem is, if the user manually writes the language name (doesnt click on the autocomplete), this callback function won't get called, and therefore the hidden ID won't be set - I would have to search for it by name in the database.

Is there a practical way to handle this kind of an issue?

Comment: What do you mean by manually select, through keyboard?

Comment: E.g. I start to write "Ja", I get an autocomplete with "Java", but I dont click on the autocomplete - I just write the 2 remaining letters myself. And in this case, the callback function doesnt gets called (atleast not with the plugin I'm using).

Comment: Yes it will not be called because you are not selecting it from the autocomplete. Instead of using the hidden field why don't you use the textbox value?

Comment: Because it would require alot of transformation on the PHP level (my actual field has much more data - not as in the example above). I know it won't get called - but is there a way around this? To somehow force the change if a user specifies a value from the dropdown manually?

Comment: Probably, you need to manually search for the entered text in source object and set corresponding id in hidden field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a *local* data source, this is pretty easy--just see if the user's entry is inside the source array:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    change: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.item) {
            /* User selected an item. value is ui.item.value */
        } else {
            if ($.inArray(this.value, availableTags) >= 0) {
                /* User typed item in suggestion list. value is this.value. */
            } else {
                /* User typed something that wasn't in the suggestion list */
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/PNqkB/

You could also use Scott González' [autoSelect plugin](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.autoSelect.js) ([demo](http://dev.nemikor.com/jquery-ui-extensions/autocomplete/autoSelect.html)). The advantage of using the plugin is that it should handle remote sources as well, where my example only handles a local source.

**Here's an example** with Scott's plugin using a remote data source: http://jsfiddle.net/ZEzMa/

Comment: My source is not local - the autocomplete values are gotten by ajax whenever user types a letter. I'll have a look at the scott's plugin - thanks.

Comment: Can you point out the links for remote source handling? There's alot of scripts in that repo, and couldnt find one myself.

Comment: @Tool: I linked right to the JS file you should include. If you include it after jQueryUI, you shouldn't have to do anything to get the `autoSelect` option.

Comment: @Tool: See my updated answer--I added an example using the plugin with a remote data source.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `jQuery.ui.autocomplete` plugin http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default ? If yes, you could use `change`, `close` and `search` events to handle what you want. This is far from ideal for sure, but the plugin doesn't do what you want for now. I think this could be reported as an issue on their bug tracker :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `autocomplete` has `select` event which gets triggered whenever you select any item form the autocomplete list using mouse or keyboard.

If you just type in the textbox without selecting the item from autocomplete list then the `select` is not going to trigger.

If you are only storing the selected text in the hidden field then I would suggest you to get it from the textbox value itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since jQueryUI 1.9 [response event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response) is available. You can check whether the search result returns single item. If so you can assign the id to the hidden field. In my case citiesData is a function calling Web Api.

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: citiesData,
    select: fillValues,
    search: function (event, ui) {
        $("#hdnField").val(null); //removes id if previously selected
    },
    response: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.content.length === 1) { //set id and label if only one item is found
            $("#txtField").val(ui.content[0].label);
            $("#hdnField").val(ui.content[0].value);
        }
    }
});
```